# Реально ли в плюсах создать анонимный класс через new?

Tags: c++

```
#define ClassDef class {}
typedef ClassDef MyClass;
int main() {
    ClassDef class0;
    MyClass* class1 = new MyClass;
    MyClass* class2 = new ClassDef; // error: types may not be defined in a new-type-id
}
```

Так же интересно, возможно ли как в джаве создать анонимный наследованный класс и сразу определить в нем методы
Вместо этого:

```
class Something { public: virtual void run() = 0; };
void run(Something* s) { s->run(); }
int main() {
    class : public Something { void run() {} } MyClass;
    run(&MyClass);
}
```

Сделать как-то так:

```
class Something { public: virtual void run() = 0; };
void run(Something* s) { s->run(); }
int main() {
    run(new class : public Something { void run() {} });
}
```

Comment: Хотелось бы в одну строку добавлять элементы.
Типа Manager.add(new My() { void run() {} }), 
а не городить десять строк на это: My* my = new My() { void run() {} }; Manager.add(my);

Answer (score 1):

Может вас заинтересуют лямды?

```
class Manager {
    typedef std::function<void()> Runner;
    void add(const Runner& runner) {
        runners.push_back(runner);
    }
    void execute() {
        for (r : runners) {
           r();
        }
    }
    std::list<Runner> runners;
};

int main(...) {
    ...
    Manager mgr;
    ...
    mgr.add([]() { /* do something */})
    ...
    SomeVar someVar;
    ...
    mgr.add([someVar]() { int a = 5; int b = 6; someVar.callSomething(a+b); })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Было решено сделать так (костыльно, но ничего лучше не придумал):

Manager class:

```
class Manager {
    // ...
    void add(Something* smth) { /* add */ }
};
```

Something class:

```
typedef void (*Func)();
struct Something {
    char* name;
    Func run;
    Something(char* n, Func f) {
        name = n;
        run = f;
    }
};
```

main:

```
mgr.add(new Something("Name1", [] {
    // todo run1
}));
```